# SSRS two category label in Bar chart issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a horizontal column chart defined like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apsjd.png)

And my chart looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQnOG.png)

You can see that «Cal_pg_tema_rrccname» is my first Y axis and «Cal_pg_obra_rrccname" is my second Y axis.

The first axis shows A,B,C becuase I 've hidden it, this info I show it in Expr. Don't worry for that.

My problem start when I run the chart. The result is this one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuoP8.png)

SSRS truncates my second axis text label with an ellipses (...) in the first case and in the last case only show the first character (P) directly. But I need to show the full name of the category axis.

In the axis proprieties I set it to enable wrap text like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeHy0.png)

Even I set the label rotation to put the text label in horizontal whit the hope to see them complete:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMiID.png)

But the effect only works with the first Y axis:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew3XP.png)

I suspect all the the configurations only works with the first Y axis.

How I can rotate the second Y axis and wrap theirs text labels?

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, which when modified could get you format you require:

In category group properties you should only have one category group which is labelled:
Fields!abc.value + "  " + Fields!def.value

With in group expressions use this same expression to group on.

With in vertical axis properties amend enable auto fit, labels can be rotated 45 degrees.